# Cyclic group action and finite invariant set

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, gn.general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $(X, d)$ be a compact metric space and $G$ a discrete group acting on $X$ such that, for each $g\in G$, the mapping $x\mapsto g\cdot x$ defines a homeomorphism on $X$

> Is it true that the existence of an infinite $G$-invariant set will imply that the group is cyclic?

Given $G$ is cyclic, for instance $G = \mathbb{Z}$, the action of $\mathbb{Z}$ acting on the unit circle does not have any invariant sets.
Here is my attempt on the other direction: Assume $S$ is a $G$-invariant set and we fix $g\in G$. Then $\langle\,g\,\rangle\cdot S = S$ because for each $s\in S$, we have $g\cdot s\in S$, and hence $g^{-1}\cdot(g\cdot s) = s$. Because $g$ is arbitrarily fixed and $G\cdot x$ is dense in $X$ for each $x\in X$, for a fixed $s\in S$, we have:

$$
\forall\,h\in G,\hspace{0.2cm}\langle\,h\,\rangle\cdot s\subseteq S = \langle\,g\,\rangle\cdot s\,\implies\, \langle\,g\,\rangle\cdot s = G\cdot s
$$

> Then, if there exists $h\notin\langle\,g\,\rangle$, what conditions do I need to conclude that $h$ is some $\epsilon$ away from infinitely many elements in $\langle\,g\,\rangle\cdot s$, or can I always conclude that?

The first question is inspired by the following particular case: when $G = \mathcal{F}_n$, the free group with $n$ generators and $X$ is the [Gromov boundary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gromov_boundary) of $\mathcal{F}_n$ (we can view $X$ as the set of words with infinite length), given $x, y\in X$, define a metric $\delta(x, y) = \operatorname{exp}(-\vert\,x\wedge y\,\vert)$ where $\vert\,x\wedge y\,\vert$ is the first $k$-th digit where $x$ differs from $y$. Also, for each $g\in\mathcal{F}_n$ and $x\in X$, define $g\cdot x = gx$. In this case $(X, \delta)$ will be a compact metric space and one can show that the existence of a finite invariant set in $X$ implies that $G$ will be cyclic.

Therefore, I wonder if this will be true for an arbitrary discrete group acting on a compact metric space. Any hints to either question will be appreciated.

**Update**: thanks for YCor's inputs, in the first question, "infinite" cannot be replaced by "finite". A counter-example will be that the group of homeomorphisms of the unit circle $G$ acting on the unit circle $\mathbb{T}$. In this case, for each $S\subseteq\mathbb{T}$ and any subgroup $H\leq G$, $H\cdot S\subseteq S$ iff $H\cdot S=S$. Hence any subgroups of $G$ that fixes a finite set must be uncountable and hence such a group will not be cyclic.

**More Updates**: This question was already answered in **MS** and here is the [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4589616) to the answer.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I meant to consider only minimal action but forgot that in such case any invariant sets will be dense or equal to $X$. I might need to consider not only minimal action and hopefully there will be a counter-example.

Comment: The empty set is always a finite invariant set. You mean a finite orbit?

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti Inspired by your example, I am tempted to consider a more general case: when $G$ is finite, $X$ is finite and all topologies are discrete, I can assume $G$ is a subgroup in $S_n$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and the size of $X$ is bigger than $n$. If I let the group action be permutation, because we want each mapping $x\mapsto g\cdot x$ to be homeomorphic, each element in $G$ has no fixed points. Can the existence of a finite non-empty invariant set implies anything about $G$? I believe there will be no invariant sets in such case and I need to at least assume $X$ is infinite

Comment: For "almost" all metrizable compact spaces $X$, the stabilizer of any finite subset (empty or not...) is non-cyclic, and usually uncountable.

Comment: @YCor By "stabilizer of a finite set", do you mean a subgroup $H\leq G$, and a finite set $F\subseteq X$ such that $H\cdot F = F$? If this what you mean, could you explain why or provide a reference? Also, how about a stabilizer of an infinite set?

Comment: The stabilizer of the subset $F$ is the set of $g$ such that $gF=F$. For, say, $G=\mathrm{Homeo}(X)$ with $X$ the circle, the stabilizer of every finite subset (and also the pointwise stabilizer) is uncountable. This is quite straightforward. Actually, the stabilizer of an arbitrary subset $F$ is uncountable iff $F$ is not dense.

Comment: @YCor Thank you and I believe you answered the first half of the first question. For the second half, again in your example, if I let $F$ be a countable dense subset of the circle, can I know the structure of the stabilizer of $F$?

Comment: @SanaeKochiya oops, I was not careful. What I should have said is that for an arbitrary subset $F$, the *pointwise* stabilizer is trivial if $F$ is dense, and uncountable otherwise. For $F$ dense, I'm not sure what to say about its stabilizer. I guess that if $F$ is *countable* and dense then its stabilizer is also uncountable.

Comment: With the question as currently written won't $X$ itself be an infinite invariant set regardless of $G$?

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti I am sorry for my delayed response. I should have mentioned that I am looking for a non-trivial invariant set (a non-empty proper subset). This question was already answered in MS and here is the link it https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4589616

Comment: You are not imposing any conditions on the considered invariant sets, and therefore any orbit of a non-transitive action provides an obvious counterexample to the first question.